# Externalize configuration files

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Title: How can a Java Spring Boot application read JSON config files from a configuration server?

Description:
I have recently moved the config folder from the Resources directory to a configuration server. The application.properties file is already present under the properties directory on the configuration server and is working as expected. I have made the necessary updates to the search path and provided spring.config.location in the bootstrap.properties file. However, my application context is not reading the JSON config files. Interestingly, if I directly hit the URI, it returns the JSON response, but the application fails to read it.

Properties added in my Spring Config server:

```
spring.application.name=config-server
repository.name=app-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${repository.uri:https://myapp.repo.dev.com/${repository.name}.git}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.label=${repository.label:master}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=${repository.searchpaths:properties,properties/{profile},${repository.searchPath:config,config/{profile}}
```

Config changes made in Spring Boot Application:
bootstrap.properties:

```
server.port:8081
spring.application.name=myapp
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=${config.uri:https://localhost:8088}
spring.cloud.config.username=xxxxx
spring.cloud.config.password=xxxxx
spring.cloud.config.name=${spring.application.name}
spring.cloud.config.location=classpath:/properties, classpath:/config
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: please show us the `spring.config.location` declaration

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the following dependencies in your pom.xml file:

   org.springframework.cloud
       spring-cloud-starter-config
2. Update bootstrap.properties
   In your bootstrap.properties file, make the following changes:

> ```
> server.port=8081
> spring.application.name=myapp
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
> spring.cloud.config.uri=${config.uri:http://localhost:8888}
> spring.cloud.config.username=xxxxx
> spring.cloud.config.password=xxxxx
> spring.cloud.config.name=${spring.application.name}
> spring.cloud.config.profile=${spring.profiles.active}
> spring.cloud.config.label=${spring.cloud.config.label:master}
> spring.cloud.config.allow-override=false
> spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
> ```

3. Place the file in the appropriate search path on the configuration server, such as config/myapp.json.
4. Read JSON Configurations:
   In your application, you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to bind the properties from the JSON file to a Java bean.
5. Make sure that your Spring Boot application has access to the configuration server's URL and credentials to fetch the JSON config files successfully.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration) is very good guide for spring config server you can read

Comment: Thankyou for response Soheil, I actually added these properties and it is still behaving same. I don't need to convert the JSON files to Java object. I need to pass the whole json file to the logic. In current logic it reads the json files from config folder which is present under resources directory and applies the logic.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to load these JSON files externally from jar , so that any change in json file will  not require the rebuilding of JAR.